# make ngrok proxy to wss:// - how?

Tags: ssl, websocket, ngrok

I have a web server written in Golang that provides on port 16200:

- http://localhost:16200
- ws://localhost:16200/ws

There isn't any SSL code in the web server, and it works great locally.
If I run `ngrok http 16200`, however, ngrok sets up a https proxy so the page address is `https://......ngrok.io`, which works fine. But when it tries to connect to the websocket server:

- it can't connect to ws://...ngrok.io/ws because it's insecure
- for some reason it does not proxy to wss://...ngrok.io/ws

when you try to connect to ws:// you get "not allowed to run insecure content".
when you try to connect to wss:// you get "socket is not connected"